# How call the "create" action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I'm working in a rails app (rails 2.3.8), and I created a resource called articles. I need a form who call the create action in that controller. I used a form_remote_tag, but I can't call correctly the "create" action, the app always call de "new" action.
I used several different combinations, the last one is this

```
  <%=form_remote_tag :html => { :action => url_for (:action => :create)} %>
```

How a could do this?. 
I can't use the for_remote_for or the form_for because that form will feed more tan one table in my database.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are over complicating it:

```
<%= form_remote_tag :action => :create %>
```

Also, be sure that this is what you truly need. You say you want to create multiple objects in the form, which is why I think you may be after `form_remote_for` coupled with `fields_for` rather than `form_remote_tag`, but from your question I don't fully understand.

Comment: I used the form_remote_tag :action => :create , but the problems persist: the html form call the articles/new instead of the articles/create